# REST API DELETE call not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a custom SharePoint site built using Angular JS & custom REST service built in C#, which Add/Edit/Delete items in SharePoint lists. The site is exposed externally.

The problem I am facing is with Delete calls. It's working fine internally (within internal network). However, If someone tries to perform delete operation while accessing the site externally, its giving 403 Forbidden error.

this issue is only with Delete calls. Get & POST are working fine.

Comment: are you trying to delete with same user login while using site internally and externally ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same user. he is able to execute all the calls except Delete & Put.